# Tkinter custom button image not fully shown

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I'm making a board for the Tic Tac Toe game and I wanted to add a round image for the buttons.
I've managed to add it but the image is not fully shown and its not rounded.

This is the code:

```
    def create_grid(self):
        grid_frame = tk.Frame(master=self, bg="#F6F1F1")
        grid_frame.pack()
        self.button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="button.png")
        for row in range(3):
            self.rowconfigure(row, weight=1, minsize=50)
            self.columnconfigure(row, weight=1, minsize=75)
            for col in range(3):
                button = tk.Button(
                    master=grid_frame,
                    text="",
                    font=font.Font(size=36, weight="bold"),
                    image=self.button_image,
                    highlightthickness=0,
                    border=0,
                    width=100,
                    height=100,
                )
                self.cells[button] = (row, col)
                button.grid(
                    row=row,
                    column=col,
                    padx=5,
                    pady=5,
                    sticky="nsew"
                )
```

button should be rounded like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/04yH6.png

and its showing like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVldC.png

Comment: I managed to do it (almost) using Photoshop lol, but now I don't know how to center it - https://prnt.sc/Lg7Q6muiltGI 

(the background is black so you can see the issue more clearly, and when the button is clicked you can see the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like *the round button* is not in the center inside the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resize the `button_image` to fit as right now the image is too large. You can do this with `self.button_image = self.button_image.subsample(2, 2)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not do it. I researched it, and as I understand, the only way to resize it is to use image.zoom() or image.subsample(), but i don't know how to use those. nothing is happening.

Comment: @Pavle I fixed it to use subsample not resize. My mistake.

Comment: Thanks! That works! https://prnt.sc/iNzNpzTtEV6R